# Import WordPress showing blank screen

Tags: php, xml, linux, wordpress

When I try to import a wordpress xml file using "Import Wordpress" utility, I get blank screen. Here are the screenshots.

[image]

After I click "Upload file and import"

[image]

I tried this with multiple xml files, in fact I exported my wordpress file into xml and tried back importing it, all it does is just adds the xml files under "Media". Does someone know how do I trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

1. Since I am on linux, I checked the logs  `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`

   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-importer/parsers.php on line 61, referer: http://wordpresselbxxx.amazonaws.com/wp-admin/import.php?import=wordpress
2. `yum install php-xml`
3. Stop and Start apache
   `service httpd stop` and
   `service httpd start`

Still need to figure out Slider Revolution error

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I would look at is the error being reported by "Slider Revolution" plugin.  Typically plugin incompatibility causes this.  The [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors) has further information to solve the "The White Screen of Death" error you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you @onerockscott, added my answer. Still need to figure out Slider Revolution error